# Any character to convet ◕‿◕ to a sad face

Tags: unicode, smiles

Using AutoHotKey when I type `:)` it will converted to ◕‿◕  (I found it [here](http://unicodeemoticons.com/)).

Now I want also convert `:(` to a similar one but I could not found a Unicode character for its lips. Do you know any one?

Comment: (ﾉ◕ヮ◕)ﾉ*:･ﾟ✧ Love the link!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a character [here](https://gist.github.com/157796)! ◕︵◕

Here is its AutoHotKey script, to use, install AutoHotKey and save the script in `smily.ahk` file and open it.

```
::><::ツ
:::-(::☹
:::-)::☺
:::)::◕‿◕
:::(::◕︵◕
::;)::◕‿↼
:::|::⊙﹏⊙
```

Comment: I believe the second `:)` should be `:(`

Comment: Hehe, I too put some Unicode emoticons in an Autohotkey script, however I didn’t use hotstrings; instead I made a chord hotkey (Ctrl+K,O; Ctrl+K,E, etc.) for them in order to have better control and avoid accidentally inserting them.          (Is that filename correct?) [ఠ_ಠ](http://wrttn.me/30dbfd/)

Comment: @Synetech Feel free to add your script to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

**`⁔`** (U+2054 INVERTED UNDERTIE) should work.

Comment: Doesn't display for me.

Comment: Thanks, Your character fit better for a sad face but Font coverage for this `◕︵◕` is far better than `◕⁔◕`.

Comment: @PHPst, the second one looks better because the frown is further down (below the eyes); the first one is too high (between the eyes). I can’t vouch for font coverage, but both work on my old XP system (though that might be because I have installed some extra Unicode fonts over the years).

Comment: @Synetech Press superkey+r and copy `◕︵◕ ◕⁔◕` to text box to see the issue.